# Storyboard not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, iphone

Hello I am facing the issue of my storyboard not displaying correctly like my simulator.

What I've done so far:

**Made Simulated Metrics iPhone 4.7**

**Cleared all constraints**

**Disabled Auto Layout constraints**

**Disabled Size Class constraints**

It seem like it was working yesterday[image: My Screen]

But it seems everything is shifted down and right

Edited: 
Tried adding constraints
[image: The status bar appears and there are black on top and bottom]

Comment: Did you start by applying constraints to the views in the storyboard?

Comment: You haven't added auto layout constraints. Or they're not correct.

Comment: @Wain No I didn't start by applying constraints

Comment: @Fogmeister do I have to do constraints because yesterday I didnt and it worked fine.

Comment: So how are you expecting the views to act as their superview is resized ? Worked fine on what size screen (and what size is configured in the storyboard) ?

Comment: I think yesterday you were probably on the iPhone 6+ simulator. The problem you have is that all iPhones are not equal. The views will not always be the same size. You can solve this with a lot of code or by having auto layout constraints.

Comment: @wain I was developing only for iphone 6 and using an iphone 6 simulator. I know you want to use constraints if you want to develop for other iphones Now that I started adding constraints, it seems like it's acting even werider

Comment: @Fogmeister look what happens when I add constraints to my storyboard

Comment: Well, the trick is to add the correct constraints. Just like with code you can't just add any code.

Comment: Well what if I want to just develop for the iphone 6?

Comment: You can't. If you want to release to the App Store then you can restrict it by OS version not device. iOS 8 covers all 4 sizes of iPhone.